# how to load a single-column csv file into a specific column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with five columns (id,name,age,number,email) where (column 'id' is Pk and has auto_increment) and a single-column `csv` file containing information only for column 'number'.  How can I load this file in `mysql`.

I have tried this but didn't work:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/dnd_220116.csv'
into table testing FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@dummy,@dummy,number,@dummy);
```

Comment: _I have tried this but didn't work._ --> What does that mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: Not actually an error but only one row was executed out of about 2487 contact list.                                                                                               Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.47 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
    INFILE 'C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\Downloads\\dnd_220116.csv'
    INTO TABLE `<database_name>`.`testing` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
    FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' 
    TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(`number`);
```

Comment: Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.10 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from testing.testing;
+----+------+------+----------------------+-------+
| id | name | age  | number                  | email |
+----+------+------+----------------------+-------+
|  1 | NULL | NULL | "07035489309"
"07039 | NULL  |
+----+------+------+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: only one row was executed out of about 2487 contact list

Comment: @VictorAdewale  Hi, If the solution has worked perfect for you. Please do mark the answer as an accepted one ;-)

Comment: @VictorAdewale Are you a beginner to MySQL?